# Does injectivity of dual imply injectivity of pullback by a surjective submersion?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, category-theory, differential-forms

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu.

Does Problem 18.8 below follow from an earlier exercise?

Problem 18.8 (Pullback by a surjective submersion)

[image]

Problem 10.5a (Injectivity of the dual map)

[image]

My thought is that just as we have a dual for k-covectors:

[image]

[image]

So do we have a dual for k-forms, although that might be what this exercise is trying to prove.

One reason I think Problem 10.5a doesn't apply is that that $\pi$ is a submersion is used to prove $\pi^{*}$ is injective (see below), while Problem 10.5a does not seem to say anything explicitly about submersions. Either that or the proof below is just a proof that is alternative, direct and doesn't rely on category theory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 18.8 can be proven in the following way (where I hope to not miss anything important hiding under the surface; let me know if you find issues in the proof!).

You should first note that the pullback map $\pi^*$ is the dual map to the map $\pi$. Now, a general fact from linear algebra is that for any linear map $f$, $$f\text{ injective } \Longleftrightarrow f^*\text{ surjective,}\\ f\text{ surjective } \Longleftrightarrow f^*\text{ injective.} $$ So in your case, if $\pi$ is surjective, $\pi^*$ is an injective homomorphism of vector spaces and you are left showing that it respects the algebra structure on $\Omega^*(M)$, i.e. that everything fits well with the differential. I think that you will need the property of being a submersion in that. Try to proceed with what I wrote, if you can't, I will work out a solution and put it here.

Comment: You agree that Problem 10.5a is sufficient to prove Problem 18.8? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realise that you put problem 10.5a, sorry. I do indeed agree that this suffices provided that you know that $\pi^*$ is a morphism of algebras not only of vector spaces. If you know that already, you should be fine proving problem 10.5a.

Comment: Did you mean instead "If you know that already, you should be fine proving Problem 18.8" ? No need to say sorry. Thanks.

Comment: That’s what I meant, yes

Comment: @SeleneAuckland If this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Wait, I just realized a potential flaw. $\pi$ is not necessarily a linear map right?

Comment: @Selene:  You are correct that $\pi$ is not necessarily linear.  In fact,$\tilde{M}$ and $M$ need not be vector spaces, so "linearity" is meaningless!  On the other hand, saying $\pi$ is a submersion means that $\pi_\ast: T_p \tilde{M}\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)} M$ *is* a surjective linear map.  So, apply what James said, except using $\pi_\ast$ instead of $\pi$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, that's a relief. Thanks!